# Is it beneficial to use a taper for the feed input of a PCB antenna?

Tags: impedance, transmission-line, pcb-antenna

What is your opinion on using a taper for the feed input of a PCB antenna? Say the feed is 2mm wide and the transmission line is 0.45 mm. Would a taper just cause more impedance mismatch? Or would it smooth impedance transition? Would it just be better to use a constant 50 ohm transmission line all the way up to the feed input like in image 2 in green? Here is the explanation from the taper image source PDF: "The taper is needed in order to compensate the abrupt step transition encountered between the microstrip line feed and the antenna."

It seems like the widening of the taper would lower the impedance of the transmission line above the ground plane, but then once it leaves the ground plane and enters into the feed arm of the antenna, the impedance will go much higher with no ground plane underneath, so it seems like maybe the taper would be counterproductive in the sense that it would cause a more drastic transition in impedance, causing more reflections as a result. Although I am not knowledgeable of the effects of impedance on a trace with no ground plane underneath vs with a ground plane underneath, but normally the closer the ground plane is to the trace above, the lower the impedance of the trace. So if there is no ground plane it seems like the impedance would be much higher.

Also, would the taper possibly help to guide the currents smoothly into the transmission line if the skin effect is keeping them on the outer edges of the feed arm when the receiving signal is coming back to the transceiver from the antenna?

And what about the miter? Is this any benefit at all? Explanation from the PDF: "The miter is used to avoid a right angle microstrip bend, which results in a poor current flow on the
stub."

Taper image source: http://edge.rit.edu/edge/P11252/public/PIFA%20Antenna%20Design.pdf

[image]
[image]

Comment: regarding the mitre, yes it is useful. Angles in traces have different impedances than the straight sections of traces. This can cause reflections. The mitre attempts to keep the impedance relatively constant. However, I think in the top diagram, it cuts a little too much off.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy If the mitre illustrated in the OP's diagram was solely to maintain transmission line impedance round a bend, then not enough is being cut off. However this is part of an antenna layout which is meant to be used as-is, so that assumption is risky.

Comment: A taper may or may not be the right thing to use, depending on how the antenna has been designed. Does it present the right impedance to a narrow line with a step to the antenna, or to a line of its native width? An often more important consideration, and one that's harder to specify and check, is what the ground is doing between the feedline and antenna. Forcing the ground currents to divert between them adds just as much stray series inductance as doing that to the signal lines. It's best if the antenna layout terminates 'away' from the antenna in the same line style that you will feed.